# Find the inverted matrix of $A=(a_i,_j),a_{i,j}={\dbinom{j-1}{i-1}}$

Tags: matrices, determinant, inverse

> Let be $A=(a_i,_j)\in M_{n+1}(\mathbb{R})$ defined for all $(i,j)\in [\![ 1,n+1 ]\!]^2$, by $a_{i,j}={\dbinom{j-1}{i-1}}$. Let's show this is invertible and determine its inverted matrix.

To my mind, one had to start like this:

A is invertible if its determinant is different from 0.

- I tried to implement Sarrus'rule, trying to create a general
  formula:: $$\sum\limits_{i=j=1}^{n}\prod_{i=j=1}^n \dbinom{j-1}{i-1}-
     \sum\limits_{i=j=1}^{n}\prod_{i-j=0}^n \dbinom{j-1}{i-1}\neq0 $$

  but this one is definitely flase...
- An hint was to use the basis $(1,X,...,X^n)$ and $\phi$

  \begin{cases} \phi:&\mathbb R_n[X]\rightarrow R_n[X]\\ &P\rightarrow
     P(X+1) \end{cases}
  The idea is to prove that $\phi$ has $A$ as matrice in the canonical basis $(1,X,...,X^n)$ and then invert $\phi$.

I know that  $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}X^k=(X+1)^k$, but that's all... I was said that $\phi (X^j)$ should be equal to $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}X^k$, but I don't understand why...

Can you help me? I'm really fond of simple examples that goes with demonstrations to understand the whole. :)

Comment: Well, then you can try the simple examples $n = 3$ and $n = 4$. :)

Comment: Also, what you are doing with the determinant doesn't make much sense to me (you cannot have a product inside a sum using the same index), but you shouldn't think about determinants too much here... you are asked for the explicit form of the inverse, not just its existence.